# фильтрация по нескольким значениям одновременно

Tags: javascript

подскажите, пожалуйста, как использовать фильтр для перехвата нескольких значений одновременно, при условии, что искомое значение является динамическим

```js
var tags = ['cat', 'animal'] //это будет динамическое значение, которое будет вводить пользователь

var list = [
{
  tags: 'cat, kitty, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'pet, animal, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'tiger, kitty, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'cat, kitty, animal, big cat'
}];

list.filter(item => {
  return item.tags.includes(/* нужно фильтровать только те, где есть оба значения из массива tags */)
})
```

Comment: результат-то какой ожидаете?

Answer (score 2):

С методом `Array.prototype.every` (ES6+):

```js
var tags = ['cat', 'animal'] //это будет динамическое значение, которое будет вводить пользователь

var list = [
  { tags: 'cat, kitty, big cat' },
  { tags: 'pet, animal, big cat' },
  { tags: 'tiger, kitty, big cat' },
  { tags: 'cat, kitty, animal, big cat' }
];

console.log(list.filter(item => {
  const itemTags = item.tags.split(', '); 
  return tags.every(t => itemTags.includes(t)); 
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var tags = ['cat', 'animal'] //это будет динамическое значение, которое будет вводить пользователь

var list = [
{
  tags: 'cat, kitty, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'pet, animal, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'tiger, kitty, big cat'
},
{
  tags: 'cat, kitty, animal, big cat'
}];

var filtered = list.filter(item => {
  var itemTags = item.tags.split(", ");
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    if (itemTags.indexOf(tags[i]) == -1)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});
console.log(filtered);
```